# How can I update this list?

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling with this problem rn : The problem have two part, first :

> Write a function named questionMarkSum that has a list as an argument. The function must replace all question marks in the list with the sum of all the numbers that appeared before it. You can assume all elements in the list are either numbers or question marks.questionMarkSum should return the updated list.
>
> Example #1: change: `[1, 2, 3, "?"]` into: `[1, 2, 3, 6]`
>
> Example #2: change: `[2, 1, "?", 5, 0, "?"]` into: `[2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 8]`

```
def mark(z):
    updated = []
    subtotal = []
    for entry in z:
        if entry == '?':
            subt = sum(subtotal)
            updated.append(subt)
            subtotal = [subt]  # include last subtotal in next sequence
        else:
            updated.append(entry)
            subtotal.append(entry)
    return updated

tests = [1, 2, 3, "?"], [2, 1, "?", 5, 0, "?"]
for test in tests:
    print(mark(test))
```

I did that and it gives desired output.

Second part :

> Make two modifications to the function questionMarkSum that you
> created for part 1:
>
> (1) If an “x” is in the list, do not update any elements with a higher
> index in the list
>
> (2) If a ten is in the list, make the next element in the list also
> equal to ten, if: (a) the previous element was not 10, and (b) there
> is already a next element in the list (that is, do not increase the
> length of the list) Call this new function updated QuestionMarkSum.
>
> Example #1: change: `[2, 1, "?", 5, "x", "?"]` into: `[2, 1, 3, 5, "x", "?"]`
>
> Example #2: change: `[2, 10, "?", 5, 0, "?"]` into: `[2, 10, 10, 5, 0, 27]`
>
> Example #3: `[2, 10]` is NOT changed (the exact same list is returned)

```
def mark(z):
    updated = []
    subtotal = []
    for entry in z:
        if entry == '?':
            subt = sum(subtotal)
            updated.append(subt)
            subtotal = [subt]  # include last subtotal in next sequence
        elif entry == 'x' :
            break
        else:
            updated.append(entry)
            subtotal.append(entry)
    return updated
```

It doesn't give me desired output & it sucks !!

Any Help !

Comment: When you break out of the loop, you never append the rest of the elements to `updated`.

Comment: You have no check for `10` in the second version.

Comment: I think [`cummulative sums`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) should kill it. At least, if you replace these question marks with zeros before counting it.

Comment: @mathfux How will that handle the special case of 10 and `x`?

Comment: @mathfux If you remove the question marks, how will it know where to put the cumulative sums?

Comment: @Barmar That's why a case of 10 is special. We need to work a little bit more on part 2. What else, you can find indices of '?' while iterating in one form or another: `[i for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i]=='?']`, `list(filter(lambda i: arr[i]=='?', range(len(arr))))` or single looping like OP did. P.S. I'm little bit lazy with this part 2.

Comment: I deleted my old answer and did a new one. I think it solves all the cases now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves all the cases.

```
def mark(z):
    updated = z.copy()
    total = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(updated):
        if val == 'x':
            break
        elif val == 10 and i < len(updated) - 1:
            if i == 0 or updated[i-1] != 10:
                updated[i+1] = 10
        elif val == '?':
            updated[i] = total
            val = total
        total += val
    return updated

print(mark([2, 1, "?", 5, "x", "?"])) # [2, 1, 3, 5, 'x', '?']
print(mark([2, 10, "?", 5, 0, "?"])) # [2, 10, 10, 5, 0, 27]
print(mark([2, 10])) # [2, 10]
```

Comment: Where is your check for `x` and `10`?

Comment: This looks like it's just solving the first part. But he already has a working solution for that. The question is about the second part.

Comment: @Barmar Updated it